# Can't call function in array

Tags: php

I'm trying to call a function inside array like this:

```
protected $settings = array(
        'prefix' => $this->getPrefix(),
    );
```

> expression is not allowed as field of default value

**getPrefix()**

```
public function getPrefix()
{
    return "hello world";
}
```

I can't do this?

Comment: No. Your object is not initiated while you define the object property, so the methods are not available. Simply do `$this->settings['prefix'] = $this->getPrefix();` in the constructor of the object.

Comment: the warning is clear, `expression is not allowed as field of default value`, so you cannot use expression as a default value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by your `protected` keyword, you are trying to set an object property. According to PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

In order to set your value, put it into the constructor:

```
class Settings
{
    protected $settings;

    public function __constructor() {
        $this->settings = array(
            'prefix' => $this->getPrefix(),
        );
    }

    public function getPrefix() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your object property must be defined when PHP compiles. However, you could simply initialize the value within your constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $settings = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->settings['prefix'] => $this->getPrefix()
    }

    public function getPrefix()
    {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd argue for a property, you _should_ initialise them in the constructor